# Programmatically create a navigation view

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uinavigationbar

So I'm trying to create an app but I'm trying to avoid the use of storyboards. Hence just using swift files along with XIB files.

I have worked a little with Navigation controllers before but not enough I guess. So far I have this:

In AppDelegate I have:

```
let homeVC = HomeViewController()
let rootVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeVC)

window!.rootViewController = rootVC
window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

My view currently is entirely empty, but with the basic "View" screen that comes with creating a new XIB file. I've set the size of that to `freeform`, and all other things like Top Bar, Status Bar are `Inferred`.

In my HomeViewController.swift I have:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "HomeView", bundle: nil)
    let objects = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)
    self.view = objects[0] as! UIView;

    print(self.navigationController)

    // customize navigation bar
    let settingsImage = UIImage(named: "settingsWheelBlack.png")
    let settingsNavItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: settingsImage, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: nil, action: Selector("selector"))
    let addStuffItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Add, target: nil, action: Selector("selector"))

    self.navigationController?.navigationItem.title = "Home"
    self.navigationController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = settingsNavItem
    self.navigationController?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addStuffItem

    print(self.navigationController?.navigationBar)
    print(self.navigationController?.navigationItem.title)
}
```

But when I run the application the navigation bar doesn't show up. Here's what I've tried besides what I currently have:

1. Add a Navigation Bar control to my XIB and connect an IB outlet to it. Also connect the IB outlet to the navigation item that already exists in the navigation bar control. Then set the title, and left and right buttons in that. Didn't work

   2. Set the title and buttons in AppDelegate straight away for the `rootVC` defined above. Didn't work.

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this after gathering some strength to read through tons of Apple docs. On this page I found this small piece of text:

`In a navigation interface, each content view controller in the navigation stack provides a navigation item as the value of its **navigationItem** property. The navigation stack and the navigation item stack are always parallel: for each content view controller on the navigation stack, its navigation item is in the same position in the navigation item stack`.

So I left my AppDelegate code as is and changed me `viewDidLoad` function to:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "EventsHomeView", bundle: nil)
    let objects = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)
    self.view = objects[0] as! UIView;

    print(self.navigationController)

    // customize navigation bar
    let settingsImage = UIImage(named: "settingsWheelBlack.png")
    let settingsNavItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: settingsImage, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: nil, action: Selector("selector"))
    let addStuffItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Add, target: nil, action: Selector("selector"))

    // Each VC within a navigation controller has it's own navigationItem property that the underlying navigation controller uses to show in the navigationBar
    self.navigationItem.title = "Home"
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = settingsNavItem
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addStuffItem
}
```

And viola!